# Figuring out a regex for Discord webhooks link

Tags: javascript, regex, discord, discord.js

I'm new to regular expressions and I'm trying to implement some code which gets the webhook ID and token from a Discord link. Example:

```
https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/ID/TOKEN/
```

I've managed to get this so far: (I'm not sure if it's correct)

```
https:\/\/.+\/api\/webhooks\/
```

The regex is supposed to find the **ID** and **TOKEN** only.

I'm new to this so any help and advice would be appreciated.

Comment: For a starting point have a look at https://regex101.com/r/B5sVYi/1.

Comment: Seconding the regex101.com suggestion, it's a great tool for playing with regexes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
let res = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/ID123/TOKEN123/".match(/discordapp.com\/api\/webhooks\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)/);

console.log(res[1]) // ID
console.log(res[2]) // TOKEN
```

Comment: just to add to/clarify the answer above, the regex could be 

    https:\/\/.+\/api\/webhooks\/(.+)\/(.+)\/ 

where the first matching group is the ID, then the second matching group is the TOKEN

Answer (score 0):

Updated regex:

```
^.*(discord|discordapp).com\/api\/webhooks\/([\d]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*)$
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).